# Create a padding when using form-inline in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I need to create from with Bootstrap.

When i use the form inline for create a form, it create a padding-right to label and input and not fill all `colmun`, but i don't need this padding .

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?**

```
<button type="button"
  class="btn btn-primary col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-12 col-lg-2 AddCatBtn">افزودن دسته جدید</button>
<div class="AddCategory col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 border-top border-bottom">
  <form>
    <div class="form-row text">
      <div class="form-inline col-md-6 ">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <label for="inputEmail4">نام دسته</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 p-0">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-inline col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <label for="inputState">زیر دسته</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 p-0">
          <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
            <option>one</option>
            <option>tow</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `col-xs-*` is removed in bootstrap 4

Comment: remove padding by `p-0` or `padding: 0`

Comment: @NishargShah i remove them

Comment: so whats problem ?